# slice a field with jq and put extra characters

Tags: string, jq

I get a field with jq with:

```
jq -r '.statuses[]   | "\(.name);\(.startTime);\(.ord);\(.app);\(.group)"'
```

It gives me:

```
HOSUE;20220601101600;220601;BANDOL;FLASH
```

I would like to get:

```
HOUSE;2022-06-01 10:16:00;220601;BANDOL;FLASH
```

Do you know if it's possible to make that with jq?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `sub` filter:

```
"20220601101600" | sub("^(?<year>....)(?<mo>..)(?<day>..)(?<h>..)(?<m>..)(?<s>..)$"; "\(.year)-\(.mo)-\(.day) \(.h):\(.m):\(.s)")
```

Answer (score 0):

To slice by position, use the `.[<from>:<to>]` notation:

```bash
.startTime | "\(.[0:4])-\(.[4:6])-\(.[6:8]) \(.[8:10]):\(.[10:12]):\(.[12:14])"
```